# How to create a menu with images and labels (HTML and CSS)?

Tags: html, css, image, menu, label

I'm having a little problem, I was trying to make a menu combining items with image and other items with labels, as in the attached image, but it doesn''t work.

[image: How it should stay.]

Next image shows how it is currently. With error.

[image: How it is currently]

I've tried with this code, but my "picture item" don't stand next to the "label item":

```css
.sprite-icons {
  background: url(../images/icons/sprite-icons_menu.png) no-repeat top left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    width: 33px; height: 30px;
}

.sprite-icons.icon_home {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
 }
 
 .icon_home:hover{
  background-position: -48px 0px;
 }
 
.sprite-icons.icon_home_active {
  background-position: -48px 0px;
}

.sf-menu{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 list-style-type:none;
 line-height: 1.0;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 10px 8px 10px;
 float: left;
 width: 99%;
}

.sf-menu a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #606060;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease; -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sf-menu a:hover{
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #ee1c24;
 padding: 10px 6px 6px 6px;
 
}

.sf-menu li{
 display: inline;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="sf-menu">
    <li><a href="" title="Home">
      <div class="sprite-icons icon_home">
      </div></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">A EMPRESA</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">SISTEMA</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TRABALHE CONOSCO</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CONTATO</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution should be use pseudo-element

```
:before
```

Example:

```css
ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.icon-tutti:before {
    content: "\e908";
}

span [class^=icon-] {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #ff653e;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-tutti"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Element</a></li>            
        <li><a href="#">Third Element</a></li>

</ul>
```

You can also use an image url as content, but using icons should be better. Try fontAwesome for example.

Comment: But the image are one item of menu, and words are others items of menu. The image there's no connection with others items in menu. Each item leads to a different page.

Comment: Sorry i didn't noticed that.
In any case you can add a class to your first item in the menu and use the :before as showned in my answer. Just remove the label "All". I'll edit my example.